# Error : The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects

Tags: c#, sql

```
public int set(string procName , object[] param)
{
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
      conn.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName,conn);
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      foreach(object o in param)
      {
         cmd.Parameters.Add(o);      // Error
      }
      int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
      return res;
}
```

The values are correctly passed via the calling function... The 2nd parameter of the function 'set' contains 2 string values.

Even at the ERROR statment the 'o' contains the first value "Computer" but represent ERROR as stated above.

Comment: could you please explain what are you trying to achieve it looks like a "generic" db access is this right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add new [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) in your collection like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(o.ToString(), o));
```

The above statement is just to show how to add parameters to the command parameters. I am not really sure why you want to send a parameter with just a single value to the stored procedure, Your method is accepting and `object` type array, if the array holds SqlParameter then you can do:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add((SqlParameter) o);
```

Otherwise you need to specify the parameter name and its value.

You can modify your method to accept an array of `SqlParameter` type objects and then add those to the command parameters.

Comment: I tired using it, but unfortunately no constructor of SqlParameter takes 1 argument.

Comment: @AkanshaBansal, yes, actually your object should have atleast two values, once is the parameter name and the other is its value atleast. Why are you sending `object[]` as parameter, and does your object contains SqlParameter ?

Comment: Yes! I am trying to make a generic function to set values via Stored Procedure into the respective tables with the required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

try change the param type.

```
public int set(string procName , SqlParameter[] param)
        {
              SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
              conn.Open();

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName,conn);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          foreach(SqlParameter o in param)
          {
             cmd.Parameters.Add(o);      // Error
          }
          int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          conn.Close();
          return res;
    })
```

You can get how to create SqlParameter [SqlParameter Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326287%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If u want create array: 
`SqlParameter[] parameter = {
new SqlParameter(...), 
new SqlParameter(...), 
new SqlParameter(...)
};`

Comment: If i does so then i am unable to create a SqlParameter[] to pass to the function 'set'.